# Ask IdentityServer 4 to user if they're logged in, stay anonymous if not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I've got an IdentityServer 4 providing identity for a set of separate MVC apps. Each MVC app provides a different set of functionality.

I put `Authorize` attributes on actions in an MVC app. If an unauthenticated user hits the action, the user is sent to the IdentityServer's login page, and authenticated, or denied permission.

How do I also allow anonymous users into the action but still hit IdentityServer to determine if the user has been authenticated (for instance by hitting an Authorize action in one of the other MVC apps)?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the `[Authorize]` attribute doesn't allow anonymous users ...

> When you mark an action method with AuthorizeAttribute, access to that
>   action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and
>   authorized.
>   *https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx*

... so you won't be able to mark an action/controller with that attribute if you want to allow anonymous users to access it.

If you just want to know whether a user hitting that action is authenticated through you can look at their `ClaimsPrincipal`, accessible from the controller. There's a handy shortcut in that you can just access the `User` object from within your controller action.

Comment: Thanks Mashton. I'm trying to find the right alternative to Authorize. I want this scenario: a user is signed into Site 1, then visits an action on Site 2 for the first time. The Site 2 action should be accessible to both anonymous and authorized users but will display slightly differently depending on authenticated state. Now when the user hits Site 2 for the first time, unless they hit an action with Authorize attribute, the ClaimsPrincipal won't have any user details. I want to fill those user details from IdentityServer.